# Change image src using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 dropdown lists called "chapter" and "question". The "question" will dynamically change according to the "chapter" list. This part works well. I want to change the image src according to the "question" list. So here is the code.

```
<div id="bookholder">
    <form name="book">
        <select onchange="setOptions(document.book.chapter.options
        [document.book.chapter.selectedIndex].value);" size="1" name="chapter">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Choose chapter</option>
            <option value="1">Chapter 1</option>
            <option value="2">Chapter 2</option>
        </select>
        <select size="1" name="question">
            <option value="" select="selected">Choose question</option>
        </select>
   </form>
</div>

<img alt="imageholder" id="imageholder" src="default.png">
<p id="imageholder-text"></p>
```

with the following javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function go(){ 
        if (document.ga_naar_rooster.pickem.options[document.ga_naar_rooster.pickem.selectedIndex].value != "none") { 
        location = document.ga_naar_rooster.pickem.options[document.ga_naar_rooster.pickem.selectedIndex].value 
                } 
            } 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function setOptions(chosen){ 
            var selbox = document.book.question;
            selbox.options.length = 0; 
            if (chosen=="0"){
                selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Select question',' ');

            } if (chosen == "1"){
                selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
                Option('question 1','11');
                selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
                Option('question 2','12');} 
            if (chosen == "2"){
                selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
                Option('question 3','22');}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#question").change(function() { 
        var nameholder= $("#question").val();
        write (nameholder);
        $('#imageholder').attr('src', nameholder + ".png"); 
        $('#imageholder-text').text(nameholder + ".png"); // For test purposes
        });
    })   
</script>
```

The code is attached here: http://jsfiddle.net/L8ur6/
The function to change the src based on the "question" list does not change the src at all. Can someone shed me some light? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `\"` instead of `"`??

Comment: sorry, I copy the code from my code with the escaping '\'

Answer (score 1):

Give Proper ID to your Question Select tag.

```
<select size="1" name="question" id="yourId">
```

Remove & Replace below Line.

```
                 <script type=\"text/javascript\">   
 replace with ==> <script type="text/javascript">
```

Try Below Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#yourId").change(function() { 
        var nameholder= $("#yourId").val();
        $('#imageholder').attr('src', nameholder + ".png"); 
        $('#imageholder-text').text(nameholder + ".png"); // For test purposes
         });
    })   
</script>
```

Comment: The \ was for escaping purpose in my code. I forget to remove it when copy and paste it here. Hmm your code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

give id to select tag like

```
<select size="1" name="question" id="question">
```

and correct code like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#question").change(function() { 
        var nameholder= $("#question").val();
        write (nameholder);
        $('#imageholder').attr('src', nameholder + ".png"); 
        $('#imageholder-text').text(nameholder + ".png"); // For test purposes
        });
    })
```

Comment: I've added the id="question", and used your function but it doesn't work either. (I corrected all the escaping \ too)

Comment: have you added js file in your html? If not then add below line <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> and make sure that all the escape characters removed. And one more thing, when you are setting question on call of 'setOptions' function then at the same time you need to set image for the default question selected option. example when you select chapter1 then adding question1 and question 2, so this time you need to set question1 image by default.