# How can I swap a picture using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I've made this header: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOWjWRy_Kks and at the place of the logo, I've inserted a picture, which is black.

When I scroll down, I want this image to be white (since the header turns black), so I've made a white version of the same image.

However I have no idea where to insert the image. I've been thinking about inserting it in the javascript code, which is the following:

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()) {
      $('nav').addClass('black');
    }
    else {
      $('nav').removeClass('black');
    }
  })
```

How can I swap in this white image using javascript?

Comment: In video, it is working fine. What is the issue here?

Comment: For a question to be well received on StackOverflow, you need to provide the mimimum complete code to see / recreate the situation.  A video on YouTube to illustrate what you want is less than desirable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image src using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248624/change-image-src-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I have not executed this code but I saw the video and with that reference suggesting following code to satisfy your requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#logoimageid").attr('src', 'blacklogo.jpg');//this will not required if default 'blacklogo.jpg' src alerady set in img tag 
     $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop()) {
      $("#logoimageid").attr('src', 'whitelogo.jpg');
    }
    else {
      $("#logoimageid").attr('src', 'blacklogo.jpg');
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your comment. I've tried it and it didn't work unfortunately. :(